# How can I fix the 'Cannot find module' error with a package in an NX monorepo using ts-node?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monorepo, nrwl-nx, ts-node

I'm currently trying to get a NX monorepo to properly build my project. I'm using ts-node to compile / create an admin-ui directory. The project.json target for it looks like this:

```
"targets:" {
    ..... other targets,

    "ui": {
        "executor": "nx:run-commands",
        "options": {
            "commands": ["ts-node src/compile-ui.ts"],
            "cwd": "./apps/vendure"
        },
        "dependsOn": ["build"]
    }
}
```

The `compile-ui.ts` looks like this (names changed):

```
import { MyPlugin } from '@project/myplugin'
import { AdvancedSearchPlugin } from '@vendure-plus/advanced-search-plugin'
import { compileUiExtensions } from '@vendure/ui-devkit/compiler'
import * as path from 'path'

async function main () {
  const ui = compileUiExtensions({
    outputPath: path.join(__dirname, '../admin-ui'),
    extensions: [MyPlugin.uiExtensions, AdvancedSearchPlugin.uiExtensions],
    devMode: false,
  })

  if (ui.compile) {
    console.log('compiling ui extension')
    await ui.compile()
  }
}

main()
```

When I run my ui target, I get the following error:

`Error: Cannot find module '@project/myplugin'`

The target is in an NX app and the @project/myplugin is in an NX package.
For some reason, it does not recognize that it is a package.

I tried using relative paths, but NX autocorrected those to use the proper path.
Then I tried to run the compiled compile-ui.js file in the dist folder, which brought other problems I couldn't solve.

The project itself should be configured appropriately, the apps and packages are in the base tsconfig of the mono repo.

Is this not possible with ts-node?
Thank you very much!